# Not expected constructor called

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor

I'm looking into **C++11** move constructors but something doesn't work. In fact the issue is even  before I started writing such a constructor. Here's a code snipped:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Object {
    static std::ostream& log(Object &obj) {
        std::cout << "Object::id = " << obj.mId << "::"; 
        return std::cout;
    }

    unsigned mId = 0;
    std::string *mText = nullptr;

    unsigned nextUniqueId() const {
        static unsigned id = 0;
        return ++id;
    }

    const std::string textInfo() const {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "mText @ " << &mText;
        if (mText) oss << " = " << *mText;

        return oss.str();
    }

public:
    Object() = delete;
    Object& operator= (const Object&) = delete;

    explicit Object(const std::string& str) : mId(this->nextUniqueId()), mText(new std::string(str)) {
        Object::log(*this) << "constructor::one-argument\n";
    }

    Object(const Object& obj) : mId(this->nextUniqueId()), mText(new std::string(*obj.mText)) {
        Object::log(*this) << "constructor::copy\n";
    }

    virtual ~Object() {
        Object::log(*this) << "destructor::" << this->textInfo() << "\n";
        if (mText) {
            delete mText;
            mText = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

static Object get_object() {
    return Object("random text");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Object a("first object");  // OK

    /*
     * Expected behaviour: inside get_object() function new Object is created which is then   copied into
     * variable b. So that new ID should be given.
     */
    Object b = get_object();  // What the hell?! Not what expected! Why?

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is similiar to this:

```
Object::id = 1::constructor::one-argument    
Object::id = 2::constructor::one-argument
Object::id = 2::destructor::mText @ 0x7fff32c25f70 = random text
Object::id = 3::constructor::copy

Object::id = 3::destructor::mText @ <DIFFERENT THAN IN ID=2> = random text
Object::id = 1::destructor::mText @ 0x7fff32c25f90 = first object
```

I get this instead:

```
Object::id = 1::constructor::one-argument
Object::id = 2::constructor::one-argument

Object::id = 2::destructor::mText @ 0x7fff32c25f70 = random text
Object::id = 1::destructor::mText @ 0x7fff32c25f90 = first object
```

which looks like variable `b` is created on spot (something like `inline` maybe?). Frankly speaking I don't know what's going on, can anyone explain?

Comment: It's called [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). If you're using gcc try compiling with the `-fno-elide-constructors` switch to prevent copy elision from taking place.

Comment: Okay, and this RVO works always? No matter the complexity (in code) of the ``get_object()`` function?

Comment: No, there's no guarantee that it'll always happen, but it is a very common optimization technique and it'll probably be hard to prevent a compiler from not doing it by default. Also, as mentioned on the Wikipedia page *an implementation may omit a copy operation resulting from a return statement, even if the copy constructor has side effects*. So the code within the copy constructor doesn't matter. As for the `get_object()` function, if you have several return statements, and maybe they don't all return the same type (but types convertible to `Object`), you might prevent RVO, but it's doubtful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to apply "return value optimization" RVO and that's why the copy is optimized out. Note that the standard allows this despite the side effects related to the output message

Answer (score 3):

The compiler optimized out the copy/move is all...

Answer (score 3):

That is called return value optimization or RVO. The compiler opted to create the temporary returned by `get_object()` directly in the memory location of `b` in `main`. It is sanctioned by the standard and a very common optimization.